# Why is the sum of a full adder a 3 input XOR?

Tags: electrical-engineering

The S (sum) output of a full adder is made of a XOR gate. But with a XOR gate, the last row of the truth table wouldn't be true. Just wondering what I'm not understanding here.

[image: Full Adder Logic Circuit]

[image: Full Adder Truth Table]

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93713/how-is-an-xor-with-more-than-2-inputs-supposed-to-work

Comment: thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think the 3-input XOR gate in your case is actually two cascaded XOR-gates.
[image]

When $\{A,B,C\}=\{1,1,1\}$ then $Y=0$ and $C=1$ so $Z=1$

Comment: This is the key. The behavior of a 3-input XOR gate is not well defined. Some define the XOR function to be one-and-only-one and others define it as an odd parity function. Cascading two 2-input gates makes it clear that you want an odd parity function.

Answer (score 0):

You have three binary inputs that represent the same value. So in terms of total combined value you can either have zero, one, two or three high inputs. The sum output has the same value as each of the inputs but the sum output represents double that value (so by choosing combinations of 1 and 2 it is also possible to also represent zero to three). The sum should be high whenever you have an odd number of high inputs, so for total values of one or three. If you define a multi-input XOR gate as a gate that outputs zero when all inputs are zero but toggles output value whenever any input value toggles (assuming only one input toggles at one time); then that would match the expected output for the sum, since the XOR output can be seen as a parity bit which is true with a odd number of inputs.